# Request to CodeIgniter controller returns a 404 error in ubuntu but works fine on windows

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, codeigniter-3, php-7

Please I need a solution, I just migrated my well functioning codeigniter project from my windows PC to Ubuntu distro, and now I get a 404 error when I try to access my controllers, can someone please tell me what is wrong with this Ubuntu or apache installation

Comment: Yes, Linux is Case Sensitive to Controller and Method names. Windows is not. So it's very likely you've not adhered to the naming conventions. See if this helps - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

Comment: Thanks, but please i have examined my urls properly and i have adhered to the rule of case sensitivity but am still getting page not found error, and the 404 error isn't the codeigniter 404 page but the browser default 404 error. please i really need help none of my controller call is working at all

Comment: Does URL work with `index.php` in it?